# Java ImageIO suddenly stops working on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7, javax.imageio, jai

We have a servlet running under tomcat 7 that converts stored TIFF images into JPEGs for display in a web application using the Java Advanced Imaging libraries. This servlet has been working since 2011. Recently, however, it has started to fail in a very odd location. We can read the TIFF image in no problem but when we try to write the result of the conversion out to a cache file, our call to ImageIO.createImageOutputStream starts returning null.

I have been unable to find any errors in the tomcat logs that correspond to when this stops working. Restarting tomcat seems to temporarily resolve the issue, but it appears to be happening with more frequency. To my knowledge we have made no changes to java, tomcat or the code running in this servlet recently. We have the JAI libraries in tomcat's lib folder rather than the web application. What could be causing this library to suddenly start failing during the day?

Relevant code section:

```
//Get a JPEG writer and write the converted image to the output stream
        ImageWriter writer = null;
        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/jpeg");

        if(writers.hasNext()){
            writer = writers.next();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No JPEG Writer!");
            return;
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
        ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fos); //This is what is returning null
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        writer.write(resizedImage);
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Probably very hard to solve from the outside. In that sense, it is a bad questions; as you basically ask for the opinions of experienced programmers on what could probably cause such problems. In that sense "admin related" boards like superuser.com might be a (better/another) place to ask for help. My gut feeling: did you check your hardware ... maybe spurious problems with an aging hard drive?

Comment: try to create a standalone app with just this section of the code wrapped in main method  in a different machine with the same config and libraries - might help you to analyze the issue

Comment: So far, hardware seems ok. Files are being written to an nfs mounted NAS, all drives in the NAS check out ok. I agree that it's the most likely problem, but if it is, I can't find it so I was mostly hoping someone else had seen this before in their own work. Most of the online searches have people getting an error thrown at that line. As for setting this up on another machine, we've done so, the biggest problem is the error is intermittent. It will work fine for hours and then suddenly stop working at all until a tomcat restart. No pattern we've been able to find yet either.

Comment: Do you deploy the JAI JARs as part of your web application, or are they in endorsed lib or Tomcat shared lib or similar? This is important info, and should probably be added to the question. Also, have you deployed any new apps to the same Tomcat server recently?

Comment: As a side note, you don't really need the `FileOutputStream`. You can just invoke `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(cacheFile)` directly. This will most likely create a different type of `ImageOutputStream` and be more efficient. Could solve the issue or make no difference at all for the problem you see... ;-)

Comment: Also, @SlavaImeshev's answer makes some sense, where's your `ios.close()`? The `ImageOutputStream` will create it's own cache file (unless you are using `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`) and if you don't explicitly `close()` those streams, you might have a resource leak (open file handles). The cache files *should* be closed in the stream's `finalize()` method, but it's worth investigating. I think the idiom is to use a `try/finally` to make sure you always close the streams you open.

Answer (score 0):

It returns null when the output file can't be created. See the Javadoc. You've changed the filename, or the way it's generated, or permissions on the target directory, or something.

Nothing to do with ImageIO.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but as you can see, we use the file output stream immediately after being created and to get to that point in the code, cacheFile is a java File object whose underlying file doesn't yet exist. And if it were a permissions problem, I would expect the error to be consistent, but if we restart tomcat, it will go for hours to days before the error turns up again.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this doesn't happen instantaneously, this can be some sort of a resource leak, either memory of file handles. Do you see any OutOfMemory in Tomcat's stdout? Can you run lsof  and see if there too many open file handles?